# Ubuntu 22.04 US intl with dead keys can't type accents

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout

I've recently updated some packages and after a reboot, I cannot type accented letters anymore.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, I use a logitech G915TKL US International. On Ubuntu I am using the English (intl., with AltGr dead keys) layout.

To type `é` for example I just had to type `'` and then the letter `e` but it does not seem to work anymore. Also, pressing AltGr and `,` does not output `ç` anymore.

On Windows 11 I use the US International keyboard without any issues.

Did I miss something here? I've read pages and pages online but I can't find a solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: A suggestion: Create an additional user for test purposes, log in as that user, and let us know (by editing your question) if the issue is present also when logged in as the test user.

Comment: Also check your keyboard layout settings in Settings - Keyboard, Input sources. If still set on English (US, Int . with dead keys), then try changing to another layout, delete Us Int then add it back and activate it. That may "restore" things

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved by changing the keyboard layout to English (US, intl., with dead keys). You can do this on Settings > Keyboard.